# Jataveda and Kravyada forms of Agni, the vedic God of fire

Tags: vedas, agni

Agni is the vedic God of fire and sacrifice. Agni is prominent in the hymns of the Vedas and particularly the Brahmanas.In the Rig Veda there are over 200 hymns that praise Agni.

Agni is identified with energy and action,and it  is the first emanation and the sacred spark hidden within all beings.

The test by fire{Agni Pariksha}, has been mentioned in the Scriptures, which highlights the connection of Agni and sacredness, during  the Vedic period.

It is learnt that Agni has two important forms viz Jataveda and Kravyada.

Briefly explain the Jataveda and Kravyada forms of Agni.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two forms of Agni as Jataveda and Kravyada. Jataveda is invoked to burn and carry offerings except flesh to Gods and Kravyada is invoked to burn flesh. I am quoting definition from [here](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/gods/devta/vedic-gods/agni-the-god-of-fire).

> Agni is said to have two forms Jataveda and Kravyada. As Jataveda, Agni is identified with Brahman and infinite knowledge and is invoked to burn and carry the offerings (except flesh) to the respective Gods. He is the pure form, the sacrificial priest and divine messenger who intercedes between humans and Gods and thus pleasing Agni, in turn, is said to please the Gods.

> As Kravyada, Agni is obtained from the rays of the sun and is invoked to burn flesh (animal parts and corpses) in the Pitru Yajna. It is the fire of the funeral pyre and hence as such is said to be the impure form which is much feared.

[Rig veda](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10016.htm) say the same thing as:

> करव्यादमग्निं पर हिणोमि दूरं यमराज्ञो गछतुरिप्रवाहः |

> इहैवायमितरो जातवेदा देवेभ्यो हव्यंवहतु परजानन ||

> यो अग्निः करव्यात परविवेश वो गर्हमिमं पश्यन्नितरंजातवेदसम |

> तं हरामि पित्र्यज्ञाय देवं स घर्ममिन्वात परमे सधस्थे ||

> यो अग्निः करव्यवाहनः पितॄन यक्षद रताव्र्धः |

> परेदुहव्यानि वोचति देवेभ्यश्च पित्र्भ्य आ ||

> 9 send afar flesh eating Agni, bearing off stains may he depart to Yama's subjects.
> But let this other Jātavedas carry oblation to the Gods, for he is skilful.

> 10 I choose as God for Father-worship Agni, flesh-eater, who hath past within your dwelling,
> While looking on this other Jātavedas. Let him light flames in the supreme assembly.

> 11 With offerings meet let Agni bring the Fathers who support the Law.
> Let him announce oblations paid to Fathers and to Deities.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani - does Jataveda exist internally as well  i.e. inside the body ? If so does it burn the food inside and take it to devatas ?

Comment: @gansub , what I have heard is the internal agni is Jatharagni, where as the subtle one is the outside aura known as Bhutagni. May be learned one can give more details.

Comment: @ForeverLearner Hello I am referring to Vaishwanaar who is the Supreme Being according to Vedas.

Comment: @gansub  ok. Sorry I do not have the idea...

Answer (score 2):

The Oxford [translation](https://books.google.com/books?id=fgzVAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA39#v=twopage&q&f=false) of Rigveda by Stephanie W. Jamison and Joel P. Brereton gives a brief summary of various epithets of Agni including Jātavedas and Kravyād.

> E. Agni "Fire"
>
> **...**
>
> Many aspects of Agni are expressed through the variety of names and epithets
> applied to him.
>
> - Agni is **Jātavedas** as **the fire established at the beginning of the rite that continues to its end**. As an unbroken presence in the ritual, Agni Jātavedas also oversees the succession of generations, ensuring that a family’s lineage will continue.
> - Agni Vaiśvānara is the fire become the sun. As the sun, this fire sees everything and governs everyone. This form of Agni is especially associated with the king, who like the sun stands above and reaches all beings. The word vaiśvānara﻿́ means the one “relating to all men.”
> - Agni is also Tanūnapāt and Narāśaṃsa. One or another of these names—or sometimes both (I.13.2–3)—appear in the Āprī hymns, which are recited in an animal sacrifice, and they both occur outside of the Āprī hymns as well. The word ta﻿́nūna﻿́pāt describes Agni as the “son of himself,” and na﻿́rāśa﻿́ṃsa as the one “who embodies men’s praise” of the gods.
> - As **Agni Kravyād**, the “flesh-eating fire,” **Agni is the fire of the funeral pyre that consumes the body of the deceased and transports it to heaven**.
>
> Mātariśvan is sometimes identified as Agni himself, but he is more properly the one who brought the fire from heaven.
>
> **...**